# Issues resolving and cleaning output

Tags: windows, go, msys2

I am working on a fork of https://github.com/cdr/sshcode, more specifically I am working on a PR to add git4win/msys2 support to the program

The issue currently stems from these two functions

```golang
func gitbashWindowsDir(dir string) string {
    if dir == "~" { //Special case
        return "~/"
    }
    mountPoints := gitbashMountPointsAndHome()

    // Apply mount points
    absDir, _ := filepath.Abs(dir)
    absDir = filepath.ToSlash(absDir)
    for _, mp := range mountPoints {
        if strings.HasPrefix(absDir, mp[0]) {
            resolved := strings.Replace(absDir, mp[0], mp[1], 1)
            flog.Info("Resolved windows path '%s' to '%s", dir, resolved)
            return resolved
        }
    }
    return dir
}

// This function returns an array with MINGW64 mount points including relative home dir
func gitbashMountPointsAndHome() [][]string {
    // Initialize mount points with home dir
    mountPoints := [][]string{{filepath.ToSlash(os.Getenv("HOME")), "~"}}
    // Load mount points
    out, err := exec.Command("mount").Output()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    lines := strings.Split(string(out), "\n")
    var mountRx = regexp.MustCompile(`^(.*) on (.*) type`)
    for _, line := range lines {
        extract := mountRx.FindStringSubmatch(line)
        if len(extract) > 0 {
            mountPoints = append(mountPoints, []string{extract[1], extract[2]})
        }
        res = strings.TrimPrefix(dir, line)
    }
    // Sort by size to get more restrictive mount points first
    sort.Slice(mountPoints, func(i, j int) bool {
        return len(mountPoints[i][0]) > len(mountPoints[j][0])
    })
    return mountPoints
}
```

How this is used, is on msys2/git4win, you give `gitbashWindowsDir("/Workspace")` it SHOULD return `/Workspace` as it handles the unorthadox way msys2/git4win handle pathing.

and when you give it `gitbashWindowsDir("Workspace/")` it returns what is basically the same output as `echo $PWD/Workspace/` but in a window format

I am working on a step-one patch that utilizes the `strings.Prefix` stuff, 
This is what I have for this patch sofar

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    mydir, err := os.Getwd()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(os.Getenv("PWD"))
    fmt.Println(mydir)
}
```

I want to check if the input has the prefix `/` and if it does, just return that as a string, this seems to be the simple fix for `gitbashWindowsDir("/Workspace")` returning `//Workspace`
But what i think the hardpart will be for `gitbashWindowsDir("Workspace/")` as it returns the same output as `echo $PWD/Workspace/` but in a windows format (`Z:\Workspace\`)

**______________________________________________**
**______________________________________________**

Update, i have gotten the prefix trimming to work, (stupidly simple)
But now i am expiriencing this issue

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "path/filepath"
    "regexp"
    "sort"
    "strings"

    "go.coder.com/flog"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("RESOLVED: ", gitbashWindowsDir(os.Args[1]))
    fmt.Println("RESOLVED: ", gitbashWindowsDir("C:\\msys64\\Workspace"))
}

func gitbashWindowsDir(dir string) string {

    // if dir is left empty, line82:main.go will set it to `~`, this makes it so that
    // if dir is `~`, return `~/` instead of continuing with the gitbashWindowsDir()
    // function.
    if dir == "~" {
        return "~/"
    }

    mountPoints := gitbashMountPointsAndHome()

    // Apply mount points
    absDir, _ := filepath.Abs(dir)
    absDir = filepath.ToSlash(absDir)
    for _, mp := range mountPoints {
        if strings.HasPrefix(absDir, mp[0]) {
            resolved := strings.Replace(absDir, mp[0], mp[1], 1)

            if strings.HasPrefix(resolved, "//") {
                resolved = strings.TrimPrefix(resolved, "/")
                flog.Info("DEBUG: strings.TrimPrefix")
                flog.Info("Resolved windows path '%s' to '%s", dir, resolved)
                flog.Info("'%s'", resolved)
                return resolved
            }

            flog.Info("Resolved windows path '%s' to '%s", dir, resolved)
            return resolved
        }
    }
    return dir
}

// This function returns an array with MINGW64 mount points including relative home dir
func gitbashMountPointsAndHome() [][]string {
    mountPoints := [][]string{{filepath.ToSlash(os.Getenv("HOME")), "~"}}

    // Load mount points
    out, err := exec.Command("mount").Output()
    if err != nil {
        //log.Error(err)
        log.Println(err)
    }
    lines := strings.Split(string(out), "\n")
    var mountRx = regexp.MustCompile(`^(.*) on (.*) type`)
    for _, line := range lines {
        extract := mountRx.FindStringSubmatch(line)
        if len(extract) > 0 {
            mountPoints = append(mountPoints, []string{extract[1], extract[2]})
        }
    }

    // Sort by size to get more restrictive mount points first
    sort.Slice(mountPoints, func(i, j int) bool {
        return len(mountPoints[i][0]) > len(mountPoints[j][0])
    })
    return mountPoints
}
```

When it runs this, it returns

```
merith@DESKTOP-BQUQ80R MINGW64 /z/sshcode
$ go run ../debug.go Workspace
2019-11-27 10:49:38 INFO       Resolved windows path 'Workspace' to '/z/sshcode/Workspace
RESOLVED:  /z/sshcode/Workspace
2019-11-27 10:49:38 INFO       DEBUG: strings.TrimPrefix
2019-11-27 10:49:38 INFO       Resolved windows path 'C:\msys64\Workspace' to '/Workspace
2019-11-27 10:49:38 INFO       '/Workspace'
RESOLVED:  /Workspace
```

Right now i need to figure out how to detect and remove the `/*/` prefix, so that `/z/sshcode/Workspace` becomes `Workspace/`

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem with determining whether the string is prefixed by a forward slash, you can use a function like this:

```
func ensureSlashPrefix(path string) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("/%s", strings.Replace(path, "/", "", -1))
}
```

For your second problem, perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but this function would return the absolute path to the provided relative path or a similar output to `echo $PWD/path`.

```
func cleanWindowsPath(path string) string {
    base := filepath.Base(strings.Replace(path, "\\", "/", -1))
    return ensureSlashPrefix(base)
}
```

[(Go Playground)](https://play.golang.org/p/kIz2_TH8xhp)

Comment: part1) Looks like it will work, testing now


part2) Kinda, for this example, i have msys2 installed at `C:\msys64` 
when you feed a path as a argument, such as `/Workspace` msys2 gives go `C:\msys2\Workspace`, 

but since its being fed a Abs path to open on a remote linux server, it resolves this by removing the install directory path from the path, but the issue is that its putting a extra `/` at the beginning, meaning `/Workspace` becomes `//Workspace`

Comment: Oh I see, so in fact what you're looking for is a translation between a Windows absolute path like `C:\msys64\Workspace` and you're wanting an output of `/Workspace`?

Comment: Yeah, go ahead and test it out yourself, when you pass `/Workspace` as a arg inside msys2, it will read it as a path, and slap its "Install Dir" to the beginning so windows programs can open that path/file.

Comment: I've edited the answer to convert the windows absolute path to `/Workspace`. Also, I've added in a Go Playground link that works. Feel free to play around there. I re-worked the first function, too, so that it's more stable and covers more edge cases.

Comment: Curious as to how it removes the `Z:\` part, i see where it fixes and converts `\\` to `/`, but not where it removes `Z:` EDIT:
The problem with this, is if i give it the path `Z:\\msys64\\Workspace\\Dragon`, it only returns `/Dragon` https://play.golang.org/p/TsGGxtwbdR-